# jQuery ColorBox: How to pull in a group of images via ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, colorbox

I am using the jQuery [ColorBox](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) plugin. I see that the plugin supports a way of grouping together images and it also supports a way of pulling in content via ajax. Checking the examples online didn't really help pave a way for a solution for this, but I was wondering how to combine these two features and pull a group of images via ajax? In other words, I would like to be able to click a link on the page, and depending on which link is clicked, those corresponding sets of images get queued up in the slideshow (and clicking Previous and Next buttons could allow me to navigate that image set within the modal box).

Any suggestions on how to approach this would greatly be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to call the plugin on img, anchor tags. The rest is handled by plugin it self, if the url of image is given in the anchor tag then it would extract the image in modal box.